# Aggregating by a field and selecting the document with the max value of another field as a collection

Tags: mongodb

Using the aggregate framework, what is the best way to get documents with a maximum value of a field per grouping so using the collection below I would like to have functionality to return one document for each group_id having the latest date.  The second listing shows the desired result.

```
group_id date 
1        11/1/12  
1        11/2/12
1        11/3/12
2        11/1/12
3        11/2/12
3        11/3/12
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
group_id date
1        11/3/12
2        11/1/12
3        11/3/12
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I know this isn't quite what you were looking for, but you could iterate through the group ids, and do something like :

db.foo.find( { group_id : n } ).sort( { date : -1 } ).limit( 1 )

 -- for each group_id = n.

This will sort all the documents with a given group id by date, and then only return the most recent one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_max) grouping function in the Aggregation Framework to find the latest document for each `group_id`.  You will need additional queries to retrieve the full documents based on the grouped criteria.

```
var results = new Array();
db.groups.aggregate(
    // Find documents with latest date for each group_id
    { $group: {
        _id: '$group_id',
        date: { $max: '$date' },
    }},
    // Rename _id to group_id, so can use as find criteria
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        group_id:'$_id',
        date: '$date'
    }}
).result.forEach(function(match) {
    // Find matching documents per group and push onto results array
    results.push(db.groups.findOne(match));
});
```

Example results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5096cfb8c24a6fd1a8b68551"),
    "group_id" : 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2012-11-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "foo" : "bar"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5096cfccc24a6fd1a8b68552"),
    "group_id" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2012-11-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "foo" : "baz"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5096cfddc24a6fd1a8b68553"),
    "group_id" : 3,
    "date" : ISODate("2012-11-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "foo" : "bat"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I get these as the entire documents having the max date?  Should I project after the grouping and grab all the fields explicitly?

Comment: Grouping will combine the documents, which probably isn't what you are intending. I've updated the example to use the aggregation framework to find the latest document `_id`s, and an `$in` query to fetch the full documents.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks, this is great!  But shouldn't the $max id selection just choose the highest _id and not the id of the doc with the $max date?  Does ordering matter here?

Comment: @Timothy055: You're correct .. I added the `_id` selection as a quick edit and this would only work if the max `_id` correlated with the max `date`.  Have updated with a more general approach that uses the results of the `$group` as criteria to find matching documents.