# Aggregate mongodb by latest timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'd like to get the "population" of each city's last timestamp using the **aggregate** function.

In a MongoDB like this:

```
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "55354bc97b5dfd021f2be661"},
  "timestamp": {"$date": "2015-04-20T18:56:09.000Z"},
  "city": "Roma",
  "population": [
    {"age": 90,"count": 1000},
    {"age": 25,"count": 25}
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "55354c357b5dfd021f2be663"},
  "timestamp": {"$date": "2015-04-20T18:57:57.000Z"},
  "city": "Madrid",
  "population": [
    {"age": 90,"count": 10},
    {"age": 75,"count": 2343},
    {"age": 50,"count": 500},
    {"age": 70,"count": 5000}
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "55362da541c37aef07d4ea9a"},
  "timestamp": {"$date": "2015-04-21T10:59:49.000Z"},
  "city": "Roma",
  "population": [
    {"age": 90,"count": 5}
  ]
}
```

I'd like to retrieve all the cities, but for each one only the latest timestamp:

```
{
  "city": "Roma",
  "population": [
    {"age": 90,"count": 5}
  ]
},
{
  "city": "Madrid",
  "population": [
    {"age": 90,"count": 10},
    {"age": 75,"count": 2343},
    {"age": 50,"count": 500},
    {"age": 70,"count": 5000}
  ]
}
```

I have tried something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203023/aggregating-by-a-field-and-selecting-the-document-with-the-max-value-of-another), but I don't know how to "unwind" the populations after getting the latest timestamp for each city:

```
db.collection('population').aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$population' },
  { $group: { _id: '$city', timestamp: { $max: '$timestamp' } } },
  { $sort: { _id : -1 } }
  ], function(err, results) {
    res.send(results)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following aggregation pipeline will give you the desired result. The first step in the pipeline orders the documents by the `timestamp` field (descending) and then groups the ordered documents by the `city` field in the next [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. Within the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator, you can extract the `population` array field by way of the [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) operator. The [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator returns the value that results from applying the [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) expression to the first document in a group of documents that share the same `city` key. The final pipeline stage involves projecting the fields from the previous pipeline into the desired fields:

```
db.population.aggregate([      
    {
        "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 }
    },
    { 
      "$group": { 
          "_id": "$city",          
          "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
       } 
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
          "_id": 0, 
          "city": "$_id",
          "population": "$doc.population"
       }
    }       
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "city" : "Madrid",
            "population" : [ 
                {
                    "age" : 90,
                    "count" : 10
                }, 
                {
                    "age" : 75,
                    "count" : 2343
                }, 
                {
                    "age" : 50,
                    "count" : 500
                }, 
                {
                    "age" : 70,
                    "count" : 5000
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "city" : "Roma",
            "population" : [ 
                {
                    "age" : 90,
                    "count" : 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: MARVELOUS! I was struggling with the pipeline, as I couldn't get the exact order of factors. I will take a look at $ROOT operator too. Many many thanks!

Comment: @Miguel No worries :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to use `$project` instead of `$unwind`:

```
db.collection('population').aggregate([{
     $group: {
       _id: '$city',
       timestamp: {$max: '$timestamp'}
     }
  }, {
     $project: {
       population: '$doc.population'
     }
  }, {
    $sort: {
      _id : -1
  }
}], function(err, results) {
  res.send(results)
});
```

Comment: This aggregation pipeline will not have the population array in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to sort any timestamp field using aggregation, I am sorting it by the latest update time of the document. If you need you can group it later. You can learn more about [aggregate sorting here.][1]

```
aggregate.push({ $sort: { updated_at: -1 } });
```

What I do is I make blocks of aggregate actions push them into an array and execute it all together. I find it easier to debug if something is not working properly.
[1]: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/